# SQL Server on VMware

Tags: sql-server, vmware, windows-server-2012

Excuse the long question, this is my first on the board.

I have just joined an organisation that is running a mission critical SQL server 2012 on a VMWare host along with another 9 (at least) VM's (web servers and batch processing servers mainly) on the same physical box.

The Physical box is a monster. I do not have the exact CPU's and Memory at the moment, but it is big. The disks are tiered so that tier 1 is pure SSD, tier 2 is SAS with SSD cache, and tier 3 something slower. I believe failover is provided at the VM level.

We do not have a massive IT team, and no one who is experienced at the VM and SQL level. Therefore we have hit a bit of an impasse.

Myself (with 25 years development experience) and our Experienced Contract DBA believe that a much better solution which would be simpler and easier to manage would be to avoid the VM route for the database boxes.

The SQL server (and it's clustered counterpart when we implement it) should live on separate physical boxes. One of the reasons is that the DBA wants to horizontally stripe some of the larger tables, and our infrastructure team have said separate drives per NDB file are not possible with the current setup. We could put the current years data on tier 1 and older data on tier 2.

From reading VMWare best practices, the host should really only contain instances of SQL server anyway, however we have all sorts of VM's installed there.

As you can imagine, when a slowdown occurs, it's very difficult to identify the exact problem.

Our Infrastructure team maintains that this is a valid configuration, but to be honest, myself and our DBA in our 40 odd years of experience have never seen anything like it. The solution we recommend needs to last for at least 3 years before we start looking at the configuration again.

Note: Our team is made up of 4 infrastructure guys, (the main proponent of the current configuration is one of this team and has worked here since school), a few on the support team and developers (4), myself (systems development manager) and a contract DBA who has worked with some massive companies. We do not really have an Ops department who I would normally expect to know all about VM's.

My questions are (and treat this as if cost is not a major issue)

1. Is the current configuration good design/best practice?
2. Are there any benefits to the current configuration?
3. Would we not be better having two physical clustered SQL boxes at different sites and perhaps a mirrored VM host with web servers and possibly some service machines on them?

Any help or suggestions would be seriously appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would also ask the question in http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: question is broad: as long as you have fast disks that are not I/O bound, SQL Server as a VM is fine.  Read Brent Ozar's blog for great tips relating to SQL Server and virtualisation. make sure the physical host does not have CPU speed lower at idle, and set a memory reservation at the host for SQL server memory